# Error while installing packages

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I'm encountering error in installing any package using apt-get. I've tried steps given in various forums, but couldn't resolve the error. For example, if I install kcachegrind, the error code is:

[I've replaced http:// with http// just to avoid links in posting the question. So, please read http// as http:// in the code segments.]

    `lap471@admin:~/bin$ sudo apt-get install kcachegrind
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree

    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     kcachegrind : Depends: kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libkdecore5 (>= 4:4.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libkdeui5 (>= 4:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libkio5 (>= 4:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: valgrind but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: graphviz but it is not going to be installed
     libcairo-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     libgtk2-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     libpango-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     libperl5.14 : Depends: perl-base (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4) but 5.10.0-24ubuntu4 is to be installed
     libterm-readkey-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     libtext-charwidth-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.14.2-3) but 5.10.0-24ubuntu4 is to be installed
                              Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.14.2-6) but 5.10.0-24ubuntu4 is to be installed
                          Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     libuuid-perl : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.14.2-6ubuntu1) but 5.10.0-24ubuntu4 is to be installed
                    Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
     perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4) but 5.10.0-24ubuntu4 is to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies.enter code here Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

If I try `sudo apt-get -f install`, there is still an error:

`lap471@admin:~/bin$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libsensors3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl liblocale-gettext-perl libmysqlclient18
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 perl-base
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client-5.1 mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdbd-mysql-perl liblocale-gettext-perl mysql-common mysql-server
  perl-base
5 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 3 to remove and 553 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/27.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 43.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 libmysqlclient18 libdbd-mysql-perl
  perl-base liblocale-gettext-perl
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/Iconv/Iconv.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
(Reading database ... 147200 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1.gz', which is also in package mysql-client-5.1 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.5
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

The sources.list file is:

```
lap471@admin:~/bin$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120817.3)]/ precise main restricted    
# See http//help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted    
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http//archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http//extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http//extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http//archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http//archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
```

And the sources.list.d/* contains:

```
lap471@admin:~/bin$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http//dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http//dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http//dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
# needed sources vor php5.2:
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted

deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe

deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse

deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse

# needed sources vor php5.2:
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted

deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe

deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse

deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
deb-src http//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
```

Any help would be really appreciated..
Thanks.

Comment: Try this - First clear repository and then update repository...

Comment: I smell something wrong with Perl? `/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/Iconv/Iconv.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below commands,

```
sudo dpkg -P mysql-client-5.1
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Can you please add an educational explanation to your answer?  Please tell researchers why this is a suitable resolution and what your commands do.  Even if you find the commands to be basic/self-explanatory, some researchers will no follow the intention/function.